# TS2351: Cannot use 'new' with an expression whose type lacks a call or construct signature

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I have a little trouble implementing the cropperjs in my project. I keep getting the above error even though I believe it is injected right.

have a look at my code please

```
module view.pages.controllers {

export class CropToolController {

    public static $inject = ["Cropper"];

    constructor(
        private Cropper: cropperjs.Cropper
    ) {
        var image = document.getElementById('image');
        var cropper = new Cropper(image, {
          aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
          crop: function(e) {
            console.log(e.detail.x);
            console.log(e.detail.y);
            console.log(e.detail.width);
            console.log(e.detail.height);
          }
        });

    }

    private getFileUrl(id: string) {
        return this.$urlHelper.getAssetUrl(id);
    }        
}}
```

Don't know if there is an error in definition file but it seems good to me

```
export class Cropper {
    constructor(element: HTMLImageElement, options: CropperOptions);

    crop(): void;
    reset(): void;
    ...}
```

Anyone has an idea what am I doing wrong here? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You trying to inject "Cropper", but you need an Angular module to inject it. Did you try [Ng-Cropper?](https://github.com/koorgoo/ngCropper)

Comment: yes I had a look at that directive but since I have my controllers written in typeScript I found it not ideal. I would be missing typeScript definitions (which I tried to get done) but in the end I had no success with it. I believe my error is not really related to this

Comment: Pls try to inject "ngCropper" instead of "Cropper" and type result here.